# Send file (image) through socket perl

Tags: perl, sockets

I am aware on how to send files through a socket in perl (server, client)... but I was wondering if anyone could explain or give me a reference on how to send image files through a socket

Comment: Is there anything about image files that makes them different, in your situation, from any other file?

Comment: @Ben Dunlap: Ditto. @Paul: Given what you know, what have you tried?

Comment: you could modify the server side to be able to concatenate and save the incoming stream, and the client can simply keep sending the file content to the server.

Probably you need some command in the communication as well
Like 

START <session> <FILESIZE>
FILE <content.....>
END <session>

but if you dont really need to use socket, i suggest php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you are "talking to the browser", you probably need to speak HTTP? If so, you need to send the correct Headers (e.g Content-Type: image//jpeg) before sending the raw image data.

Comment: Sounds like you're implementing at least part of an HTTP server. If you haven't already been consulting it, you might find RFC 2616 (the official HTTP spec) helpful: http://www.ietf.org/rfc/rfc2616.txt